# Django TemplateSyntaxError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working with a django form, and I have a choice field. I think the problem may be that the choices are fetched dynamically, and right now there's only one value. I'm getting the `TemplateSyntaxError: too many values to unpack`. Some of the other posts seem to say that having only one value is a problem, so i adjusted my function that fetches the choices, and changed it so it added to blank options at the beginning, just as a test. However this brought up another error: `need more than 0 values to unpack`

Not really sure what to do about this, because even if there is only one value, I need it to still execute.

Form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(get_category_list())
    file = forms.FileField()
```

Category Fetch Function:

```
def get_category_list():
    cats = [(), ()]
    for i in os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/forms'):
        cats.append(i)
    return cats
```

Template Section:

```
<div id='addformdialog' title='Add Form'>
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
```

View:

```
def fm(request):
    if request.session['SecurityLevel'] != 2:
        return HttpResponse('Access Denied!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpoadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            destination = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/forms/" + request.POST['category'] + "/" + request.FILES['file'].name, 'wb+')
            for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
            destination.close()
            form = UploadFileForm()
            return render_to_response('admin/fm.html', {'categories':cats, 'form':form, 'uploadsuccess':True})
    else:
        cats = get_category_list()
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('admin/fm.html', {'categories':cats, 'form':form})
```

Comment: ... Code? Template? *Anything*?

Comment: This is a generic template error. If you want help you need to provide the code. Ideally, the template fragment and the view that is supplying the context.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I updated with some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`choices` is supposed to be an iterable of 2-tuples. You are only appending a single string, which is causing chaos due to how strings and tuples interact (I'll give you details if you really care). Append 2-tuples instead.

Comment: This didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the original bogus elements? Also, you may want to show some more code so we know that you understand what "this" meant.

Comment: No, 2-tuples. Those are two 0-tuples. Plus, you're still appending single strings. Remove the initial elements and try `cats.append((i, i))` instead.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the filename on the way back to make sure an attacker isn't trying to send you something with `../` in it.